# passing self writing Object via putExtra()

Tags: java, android, serializable

I am trying to pass over a selfwritten Object "Data" of Data.class to a newly created Activity "SettingsScreen" with the main Activity "Mainscreen"

Data:

```
public class Data implements Serializable
{
    private String ende;
    private String anfang;
    private String protocol;
    private String URLkomplett;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    private String manufacturer;
    private String type;
    private String productNr;
    private String RFID;

    private int scanArt;

    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private MainScreen main;
    private Editor edit;
    private ConnectivityManager connManager;
}
```

method in MainScreen:

```
public void optionsButton(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsScreen.class);
    intent.putExtra("data", data); // IT CRASHES HERE, data Object is NOT NULL
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And finally the OnCreate-method of SettingsScreen:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_screen);
    data = (Data) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data");
}
```

And here is the LogCat output:

```
05-14 09:35:04.040: E/Trace(1623): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-14 09:35:04.340: D/dalvikvm(1623): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 41K, 9% free 7256K/7939K, paused 65ms, total 66ms
05-14 09:35:04.370: I/dalvikvm-heap(1623): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.017MB for 1536016-byte allocation
05-14 09:35:04.560: D/dalvikvm(1623): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 8% free 8755K/9479K, paused 87ms+3ms, total 190ms
05-14 09:35:04.680: D/dalvikvm(1623): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 8% free 8755K/9479K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
05-14 09:35:04.690: I/dalvikvm-heap(1623): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.169MB for 1209856-byte allocation
05-14 09:35:04.870: D/dalvikvm(1623): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 8% free 9936K/10695K, paused 125ms+3ms, total 175ms
05-14 09:35:05.100: D/libEGL(1623): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
05-14 09:35:05.191: D/(1623): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a13f270, tid 1623
05-14 09:35:05.223: D/libEGL(1623): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
05-14 09:35:05.230: D/libEGL(1623): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
05-14 09:35:05.401: W/EGL_emulation(1623): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-14 09:35:05.410: D/OpenGLRenderer(1623): Enabling debug mode 0
05-14 09:35:07.715: W/EGL_emulation(1623): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-14 09:35:10.301: D/AndroidRuntime(1623): Shutting down VM
05-14 09:35:10.301: W/dalvikvm(1623): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300) 
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     ... 11 more
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.test.app.Data)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1279)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1233)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:6470)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1741)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1411)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at com.test.app.MainScreen.optionsButton(MainScreen.java:140)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     ... 14 more
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.net.ConnectivityManager
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1274)
05-14 09:35:10.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     ... 26 more
05-14 09:35:12.700: I/Process(1623): Sending signal. PID: 1623 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You should make your Data.class implement Parcelable instead of Serializable as Serializables have a performanceissue in android

Comment: Ok, but it's still crashing.

Comment: is optionsButton  declared with the onClick properties in your xml layout?

Comment: what's wrong with Serializable?

Comment: NotSerializableException: android.net.ConnectivityManager what's inside Data?

Comment: can you post the whole Data class?

Comment: i've added all the variables, rest is only methods working with them.

Comment: An unstated 'performance issue' has nothing to do with a `NotSerializableException`. -1

Answer (score 1):

In order to be Serialiable your class must:

1. Implements the `Serializable` interface
2. Every member inside your class must Implements `Serializable`

If those two requirements are not meet your class can not be serialized.

In your case `private ConnectivityManager connManager;` does not implements `Serializable` so it can not be serialized. This is causing the Exception. If you want to keep it inside your class and you want to serialize your class you can add the transient keyoword

```
private transient ConnectivityManager connManager;
```

Comment: I've changed it to Parcelable.. so all the Variables withing the Class need to be Parcelable as well?

Answer (score 0):

> java.io.NotSerializableException: android.net.ConnectivityManager

You have an instance member somewhere of type `android.net.ConnectivityManager`. Rethink. Make it transient, make it a local variable that is acquired on-demand, remove it, whatever continues to make your application work. But you cant' serialize them.

Comment: OK.. i have made MainScreen.class Serializable as well, and I have moved connectivityManager to an parameter of the method, thats using it.

Answer (score 0):

OK i've come up with a Simple Solution. Im giving my SettignsScreen.class a static variable Data, which i initialize from MainScreen, after the Activity has started.